# Why does google pagespeed asks to specify ETag even when cache headers are set

Tags: pagespeed, yslow

I have set cache headers to be far in future (1 year from now) and have disabled the ETags as advised by the YSlow (http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags) but Google pagespeed seems to require ETag (or last-modified)  even after the cached headers are set.

"It is important to specify one of Expires or Cache-Control max-age, and one of Last-Modified or ETag, for all cacheable resources."

The two rules seems to be conflicting each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YSlow does not advise to remove ETags in general but for some environments. When not using ETags then you should use `Last-Modified` instead.

`ETag` and `Last-Modified` are for *conditional GET-Requests* when **re-requesting an already cached and maybe expired resource**.

`Cache-Control max-age` is for defining **how long a cached item is valid** for sure without asking again. (When expired by this rule then the browser will make a conditional GET ...)

So in your case:

- Browser is caching the resource for one year. Within that year no request for this resource is done at all. It's directly served from local cache. (uses `Cache-Control` header settings.)
- Browser does conditional Request after one year expired to check if something changed. The server responds with `HTTP 304` and empty body when nothing changed. The browser continues to use its cached item in that case without the need of retransmission. (uses `ETag` and/or `Last-Modified` header settings)

(The browser may or may not respect your data. For example it is possible that a browser will do a conditional request even when one year has not been expired yet.)

For highly optimized sites the `Cache-Control` is far more important, because you set it faaaar future expire headers and simply change the URL for the resource in case it changed. While this prevents the use of conditional Requests it gives you the ability to be extremly aggressive when defining the expires header while being able to serve new versions of the resource immediatly to everybody at the same time. This is because of the new URL it seems to be a new resource in browser's view.

For Java there exists a framework called [jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) which makes use of these and other concepts without having negative impact to your site development.

Comment: Good answer but what is more important here. Adding a few bytes in the response header for every request to avoid a full content download after 1 year? Chances are that the most users have cleared their cache at least once in a year. Even there is a better chance that the site does not use the same resources that it used one year ago.

Comment: Per client view: Well, you've these extra bytes for only **one** response for a resource that will be cached then. When the browser's cache expired or it likes to refresh its cache earlier it can be done with a conditional request then. It depends on the resource but it is very likely that the additional header fields from **one** response and **one** conditional request is smaller than the cached resource. And then you won with setting either ETag or Last-Modified. I agree that it can make sense to discard these for VEEERY small resources that are smaller than these two header fields.

Comment: When there is a good chance that the site changed the resource within the Cache-Control max-age time then it was not configured properly. The Cache-Control max-age says how long a cached resource is valid **for sure**.

Answer (score 0):

`ETag` and `Cache-Control` headers are not exclusive. The reason the page you linked to recommends to remove ETags is to reduce the size of the HTTP headers.. which will at best save you a few bytes. Here's a use case where and why is still makes sense to have both:

- You provide `application.js` with one week expiry date, and an etag fingerprint
- Week passes, user comes back to your site: the file has expired, and the browser dispatches a conditional request, if the file has not been modified, the browser can decide to skip requesting the file entirely. (Last-Modified works too)

If you don't provide an `ETag` or `Last-Modified`, the browser *has* to request and download the entire file.

Good related resource: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching

Comment: The main reason mentioned on the linked site to not use `ETag` is its default configuration on Apache and IIS servers and issues with that default configuration in a multi-server environment. So you have to configure `ETag` properly on your own here or completly remove it. The smaller header size is more a side-effect but should not the reason for removing `ETags`.